# Php sessiontimeout problems

Tags: php, session

Online system is unable to maintain a session. We've set it for 3 to 5 hours but it is logging member out after 35 to 45 minutes.What could be the reason behind?

Comment: are you using cookies for session id?

Comment: By what mechanism have you set it?  If using cookies, what value do you see for session.gc_maxlifetime when you run phpinfo()?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the cookie is timed out. There could be many reasons. But if it's due to **incorrect server clock**, it's tough to figure out.

Update your time

```
 ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```